# Purpose of Initialization Vector in File Encryption and Authentication (FEA)?

Tags: authentication, file-encryption

I came across this schematic of FEA implementation using RSA and AES:

Suppose that `PKB` is Bob's public key, `PKA` is Alice's public key, `SKB` is Bob's private key, `SKA` is Alice's private key, `Ks` is the session key used by AES, `IV` is the iniitialization vector, and `F` is the plaintext.

Suppose Alice was to send Bob a message:

```
C = E_{PKB}(Ks||IV) || E_{Ks}(F) || Sig_{SKA} (E_PKB(Ks||IV) || E_Ks(F))
```

This ciphertext consists of three components:

```
E_{PKB}(Ks||IV) - the RSA encrypted AES session key along with IV
E_{Ks}(F) - The AES encrypted plaintext file
Sig_{SKA} (E_PKB(Ks||IV) || E_Ks(F)) - The RSA signature
```

When Bob receives the message, he will verify and decrypt the ciphertext.

This makes perfect sense except for the IV. I don't know what the IV is used for in this case. It seems that the IV is simply concatenated with the session key. How is this useful and how does Bob deal with the IV when decrypting the session key? What extra security does this provide? This was the schematic which my professor presented when talking about RSA. It could be possible that the IV is not needed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming AES is being used in any mode other than ECB, the IV is used in the AES encryption (the actual encryption is `E_{Ks,IV}(F)`, not just `E_{Ks}(F)`). Every mode of operation for AES that I'm aware of except for ECB mode requires an initialization vector, that is used for different things depending on the mode (in CTR it's used to produce the keystream; in CBC it's XORed with the first plaintext, etc.) Now, the IV does not need to be secret, so you *could* just concatenate it to the whole message; I'm not sure why it's encrypted with RSA, instead of having

```
C = E_{PKB}(Ks) || IV || E_{Ks,IV}(F) || Sig_{SKA} (E_PKB(Ks) || IV || E_{Ks,IV}(F))
```

But that's why it's present in the first place.